How to reliably get the amount of internet traffic used on an Ubuntu server?
I have multiple servers and they have limited internet traffic usage.
Unfortunately, the provider has not set up a system to notify the remaining traffic for the servers.
And I am also trying to build a notification system.
I was able to get the amount of traffic consumed with the following command, but this amount starts from 0 every time the server is rebooted.
ifconfig eth0 | grep -E "RX packets" | awk '{print $5}'

What should I do?

Probably all methods involve polling the interface statistics every minute and recording to persistent storage (e.g. SQLite database). For example, the vnstat package does exactly that.
There exist systems which can do this over SNMP (a common protocol for system monitoring, mainly network equipment such as routers and switches) and those could be adapted for Linux (using net-snmp as the agent). A more modern approach would likely involve Prometheus over HTTP. Fundamentally it's still the same – poll eth0 stats every X minutes; if the result is lower than previous, assume a reboot must have happened and add to the last recorded amount.
